# Push notification while in App

Tags: php, iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have successfully set up a MySQL+PHP push notification server and everything is working fine and dandy, except for one thing. If the user happens to be in the app, they do not get the push notification, which is kind of annoying. Is there a way I can modify this so it will show the push notification in Notification Center or something?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When app is running below method is called

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

You cannot add anything to notification center using SDK. If notification is received when app is not running iOS add it in the notification center. You can show alert yourself in above method like this

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
{
   //show alert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your user is in the app your app will get a message to the app delegate. See

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

in the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

You cant put a notification in notification center while the app is open. Notification center is designed to capture notifications that happen while the app is not active. However the call to the app delegate is useful as you can display the notification to the user in any way you want to, including building your own notification center style animation if thats what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I can use this to display a UIAlertView or something along those lines that will do essentially the same thing.

Comment: It does not seem that this function is being called when the phone gets a push notification. The push notifications are coming through after I close the app.

Comment: Nevermind, it is all of a sudden working. No idea why. I did not change anything. Oh well I am not complaining :)

Comment: If the app ID is correct and matches the provisioning profile app id, and the certs for the APNS are all current and match the app ID, the app is running on a real device and has called `- (void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)types` and registered successfully AND the iPhone recieves the notification while the app is running then the method will always be called on the application delagate. Quite a lot of stuff to go wrong ;)